# Function log from math.h returns wrong

Tags: c, math.h

I was getting wrong values from `log()`, so I wrote this program just for testing:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
  printf ("%1f", log(10));
}
```

This should print "1", but I get "2.302585"

Why is this and how can I fix it?

Comment: `log` is the natural logarithm.  You want `log10`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`log`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/log) function is for the *natural* logarithm with base `e`.

It seems you want [`log10`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/log10) instead.